# Simulating projectiles in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to simulate a projectile that shoots out from the ends of my pr2's arm in gazebo.

Is this possible? Are there existing code that does this or are similar I can take a look at?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56654/simulating-projectiles-in-gazebo/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-02-28**:
@mugetsu Nice idea, I have simulated a pendulum in gazebo and played around with the 'g' !! which gave various trajectories :-) . A projectile should be very much possible !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should probably be asked at http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1